# ASP.NET C# :assembly with different class libraries which are targeting different .Net versions and are internally dependent on each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

this is a legacy asmx webservice, where I have one solution file with 6 class libraries and one is exposed as web.couple of class libraries refer .net 2.0 framework(reason is they reference custom COM dll)  while rest refer .net 4.0 framework due to dll's developed in 4.0
class libraries internally refer each other due to which I'm getting compilation error?

is it even possible what I'm trying to achieve? if yes then how.

kindly suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to keep the dependent class files as different class libraries i.e built project against 2.0 since it was using legacy COM dll and then build another  class library and target them to 4.0 framework, which resolved the dependency issue.